# Large page mostly text loads slow

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

I've run nginx as a reverse server for apache for years. Tens of thousands of pages load fine, popping up right away.

I noticed a couple pages loading really slow. I narrowed it down to the amount of text in the page. Over 8 thousand characters it becomes noticeable. 40 thousand characters and it takes 14 seconds to load. Not slowly loading, it pops up after 14 seconds.

I could get rid of these few pages but am curious if there is a setting in nginx or apache I could adjust. It's a 4 core / 8 thread with 32 gigs memory on 20/150 megabit connection. I'm not seeing anything in logs or "top" indicating heavy activity when loading.

No "max" settings in my nginx.conf holding anything back, maybe gzip issue?

`gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml image/svg+xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;`

Huge images and other files load fine.

I read one suggest of turning off proxy_buffering, that made no difference.

edit:
php, mysql with javascript

Comment: 40kB is tiny. It sounds like it's taking time to generate the page, rather than time to compress or transmit the page. Perhaps you should look into that. You can use webpagetest.org to help look at public webpage performance. Not much more we can help with given the information available.

Comment: @Tim thx, it must be page generation. I tried webpagetest.org and it only fails on "first byte time". No clue where to go next, but I'll search around.

Comment: First byte time doesn't automatically mean it's page generation, but if it's higher than most other pages and static resources then it's a good clue.

Comment: You give no information on if the pages are dynamic or static, and if they are dynamic, how they are generated.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen php with javascript, so maybe a setting in php.ini? The large amount of text that is the issue is pulled from mysql. So I guess it could be a mysql setting too.

Comment: Most likely it is caused by an unoptimized application. You need to check database structures, indexing and application data caching.